# Pod install : Unable to find a specification for 'Foo'

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

i am trying to install my custom pod created and when i run the pod install i see below error. Any one can please help I did try similar links on stack overflow but no luck.

Error : Unable to find a specification for 'Foo'.

Terminal Logs :

```
ExampleApp djrecker$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Pre-downloading: `Foo` from `https://github.com/deepesh259nitk/mixedFramework.git`, tag `1.0.7`
[!] Unable to find a specification for 'Foo'.
```

Pod file

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'ExampleApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for ExampleApp
  pod 'Foo', :git => 'https://github.com/deepesh259nitk/mixedFramework.git', :tag => '1.0.7'

end
```

More pod commands output  : pod try , pod install and pod list

```
AUK03154:ExampleApp djrecker$ pod try Foo
Updating spec repositories
[!] An unexpected version directory `Foo.xcodeproj` was encountered for the `/Users/djrecker/.cocoapods/repos/deepesh259nitk/Foo` Pod in the `Foo` repository.
AUK03154:ExampleApp itrmg$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Pre-downloading: `Foo` from `https://github.com/deepesh259nitk/mixedFramework.git`, tag `1.0.7`
[!] Unable to find a specification for 'Foo'.
AUK03154:ExampleApp djrecker$ pod list | grep Foo
AUK03154:ExampleApp djrecker$
```

pod spec file

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

  s.name         = "Foo"
  s.version      = "1.0.7"
  s.summary      = "This is a iOS framework containing both objective c and swift code"
  s.description  = "This is a iOS framework containing both objective c and swift code and shows how modules with with POD"
  s.homepage     = "https://github.com/deepesh259nitk/mixedFramework"
  s.license      = "MIT"
  s.author             = { "Deepesh" => "deepesh259nitk@gmail.com" }
  s.platform     = :ios, "11.0"
  s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/deepesh259nitk/mixedFramework.git", :tag => "1.0.7" }
  #s.source_files  = "Foo/**/*.{h,m,swift}"
  #s.source_files  = "Foo/**/*.{modulemap}"
  #s.source_files  = "Foo/**/*.private.modulemap"
  # s.exclude_files = "Classes/Exclude"
  # s.public_header_files = "Foo/*.h"
  s.vendored_frameworks = 'Foo/Foo.framework'

end
```

Comment: show podspec please

Comment: @AnkurLahiry pod spec is updated to question.

Comment: Put the podspec in the top level directory at https://github.com/deepesh259nitk/mixedFramework

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Perfect i did as you told and it all works. Thats was so simple and useful answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the podspec in the top level directory at github.com/deepesh259nitk/mixedFramework